# Erlang Syntax error before end

Tags: syntax, erlang, case

I'm trying to make a dots and boxes game, however when I try to execute this code that evaluates whether a wall has been drawn, I get a 'syntax error before end' error. The code:

```
setnextwall(Start, 60) ->
    true.

setnextwall(60, Steps) ->
    setnextwall(0, Steps + 1).

setnextwall(Start, Steps) ->
    case array:get(Start, Rooms) of
        false ->
            buildwall(Start);
        true ->
            setnextwall(Start + 1, Steps + 1);
    end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last ;

; is a separator between cases, since there's no following case, it's an error